# Unable to access thumbUrl property of an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd, react-typescript

I am trying to use an uploader from antd. However I am having a hard time trying to retrieve the uploaded image.

export default function normaliseAndUploadTheFile(e:any)

```
    console.log('Upload event from 2nd func:', e);
    console.log('Type of fileList:', Array.isArray(e.fileList));
    console.log('Value of e.fileList[0]:', e.fileList[0]);
    console.log('Length of e.fileList[0] object keys array:', Object.keys(e.fileList[0]).length);
    
    
    console.log('Value of thumbUrl:', e.fileList[0].thumbUrl);
```

all the values get logged just fine but as i try to log thumbUrl it vanishes!

NOTE : thumbUrl is a very large string containing base64 value of image.(if that helps). i have wasted a lot of my time on this silly thing. pls help

[Screenshot of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3w6l.png)

i am trying to use a Upload component from antd

```
<Form.Item
          name={['blog','headimage']}
          label="headImage"
          valuePropName="fileList"
          getValueFromEvent={normFile}
        >
          <Upload name="logo" listType="picture" maxCount={1}>
            <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Click to upload</Button>
          </Upload>
         </Form.Item>
```

the normFile funcn is implemented like this :

```
const normFile = (e: any) => {
  console.log('Upload event:', e);
  const result = normaliseAndUploadTheFile(e)
};
```

Comment: `normFile` function should return a value.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.